# Blocking URL brute-forcing on my server

Tags: brute-force, url, web

Every day my server receives many `GET` requests in search of security holes. In other words, they are trying a list of words in search of a hole.

for example:

```
http://myapp.com/phpmyadmin
http://myapp.com/pma
http://myapp.com/phpini.php
http://myapp.com/phpMyAdmin-2.11.7.1-all-languages-utf-8-only
http://myapp.com/phpMyAdmin-2.8.2
...
```

(I've also found something like that: `w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec`, they are using also PHPMyAdmin weakness)

Where I can find a list with all of those words they are using for attacks? I'd like to block all of them using a list of common words.

EDIT:
My first idea is to block IP when they are trying too many times in a short time. It's a good idea or it's impossible to reach?

Comment: From the output you describing it seems that tools like dirbuster, dirsearch, dirb etc... are used. So you can start with the wordlists those tools use by default (_in Kali linux I think most of those wordlists are in /usr/share/ directory_). But don't forget that there are also some custom wordlists e.g. on github etc...

Comment: Thanks for the advice (Kali linux). I don't find any wordlists in github or similary... do you have an idea where I can find a list for start? Thanks again.

Comment: The list you are looking for is massive and grows daily. Blacklisting those things will be an impossible task. You need a different approach. Like blocking the IPs that make too many improper GET requests.

Comment: My idea was ban the ip when trying too many times from a list. Do you think it's impossible? Thanks.

Comment: @andreah perhaps search the logs for 404 HTTP responses and use a tool like fail2ban to block when there are too many.